# Angular 2 provide with use class, how to init parent class only once

Tags: angular

I have a ParentService and a few Children of it.

```
@Injectable()
export class ParentService {
   car:Car;
   get Car():Car {
      return this.car;       
   }
   set Car(car:Car){
      this.car = car;
   }
   ...

}

@Injectable()
export class ChildService extends ParentService {
    constructor(...){
       super();
       ...
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class AnotherChildService extends ParentService {
        constructor(...){
           super();
           this.Car = new Car;
           this.Car.Year = 2015;
           ...
        }
    }
```

Second thing I have is a service, with injection of the ParentService.

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService{
    constructor(private serviceProvider:ParentService){
       this.car = this.serviceProvider.Car;
       ...
    }
}
```

In each module, I 'tell' the service which child service to use in this service.
Here is one of the modules example:

```
@NgModule({
   ....
   providers: [
      {provide:ParentService, useClass:AnotherChildService},
      ....
   ]
})
export class AnotherChildModule{
    ...
}
```

The issue is:
I do see that the injected service is correct.
BUT, the ParentService is initialized twice (the constructor gets called twice), and this makes the data not to be the correct one.

E.g. in the following the serviceProvider.Car is undefined, even the car is initialized in the constructor of the AnotherChildService

```
@Injectable()
    export class CarService{
        constructor(private serviceProvider:ParentService){
           this.car = this.serviceProvider.Car;
           ...
        }
    }
```

Am I doind something wrong? what is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just need to use useExisiting, instead of the useClass.

```
{provide:ParentService, useExisting:AnotherChildService}
```

Here is a reference: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action